# Prove that $a+b=1 \iff a=2t/(1+t)$, $b = (1-t)/(1+t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive numbers. How do we prove that $$a+b=1 \iff a=\frac{2t}{1+t}, \ b = \frac{1-t}{1+t}$$ for some number $t$ such that $0<t<1$.

The reverse implication is easy to show, you just put in $a=2t/(1+t)$ and $b = (1-t)/(1+t)$ into $a + b$ and then you get $1$. But how do one show that $a+b=1$ implicates that $a=2t/(1+t)$and $b=(1-t)/(1+t)$?

Comment: I think you mean $a,b\in (0,1)$, because there are no two positive integers whose sum is 1.

Comment: It's an overkill, but $a=\sin^2x$ might be a start.

Comment: How about the parametrization $a=t,\,b=1-t$? In view of it the question should be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean $a,b\in(0,1)$ rather than positive integers, which doesn't make sense: no pair of positive integers can sum up to $1$, so the statement would be trivially true.

There's only one number $t$ such that
$$
a=\frac{2t}{1+t}
$$
and it's easy to compute it:
$$
t=\frac{a}{2-a}=\frac{a-2+2}{2-a}=\frac{2}{2-a}-1.
$$
Since $0<a<1$, we know that $1<2-a<2$, so $1<\dfrac{1}{2-a}<\dfrac{1}{2}$ and finally
$$
0<t=\frac{2}{2-a}-1<1
$$
as required. Now
$$
b=1-a=1-\frac{2t}{1+t}=\frac{1-t}{1+t}
$$
and the proof is complete.

The reverse implication is easy: for each $t\in(0,1)$ we have $2t/(1+t)>0$, $(1-t)/(1+t)>0$ and
$$
\frac{2t}{1+t}+\frac{1-t}{1+t}=1.
$$

Comment: How about the parametrization $a=t,\,b=1-t$?

Comment: @user64494 I don't see any way to use it: writing $t$ instead of $a$ is useless.

Comment: @ egreg:This is another parametrization. The question under consideration is about the equivalence, not about the usage. Also consider $a=t^2,\,b=1-t^2$.

Comment: @user64494 So what? You can have different characterizations. A quadrilateral is a parallelogram if and only if it has equal opposite sides, if and only if diagonal bisect each other, if and only if it has equal opposite angles, …

Comment: @ egreg: Thus, the required implication $a+b=1\Rightarrow \,a=\frac {2t}{1+t},\,b=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ is not true.

Comment: @user64494 Why? The proper statement is, of course, "If $a+b=1$, with $a,b\in(0,1)$, then there exists $t$ such that $t\in(0,1)$, $a=2t/(1+t)$ and $b=(1-t)/(1+t)$" as in the question. And it's true. Prove it's false and I'll believe you.

Comment: The question is unclearly formulated.

Comment: @user64494 So you downvote my answer because you don't understand the question? This is quite bizarre. In my opinion the question is very clear.

Comment: How do you get that $t=\frac{a}{2-a}$?

Comment: @user30523 If $a=2t/(1+t)$, then $a+at=2t$, so $a=t(2-a)$ and finally $t=a/(2-a)$.